# Is there a command line tool for smush.it?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

Is there a command line tool for the [smush.it](https://imgopt.com/) webservice?

I know there is a jar that you can download. But I'm looking for something I can just install with the Ubuntu package manager, aptitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trimage is a tool similar to Smush.it:

> Trimage image compressor losslessly optimizes your PNG and JPG files
>   with very little fuss.
>
> Available with both GUI and command-line interfaces, the application
>   optimizes images via optipng, advpng and jpegoptim, depending on the
>   filetype. The interface was inspired by OS X application ‘imageoptim’.

Source: [OMGUbuntu.co.uk: Trimage Image Compressor – Simple & straightforward lossless compression](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/trimage-image-compressor-simple-straightforward-lossless-compression)